# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'objectNotify' of undefined in Angular 5

Tags: ionic3, angular5

I am calling a method inside `ionViewDidLoad` in angular 5. And inside the method, I am trying to use an object declared. But for me, it is showing `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'objectNotify' of undefined` error. Here's my code.

```
export class NotificationsPage {
    public objectNotify = {};
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.notifyMethod();
    }
    notifyMethod() {
        this.objectNotify["name"] = "John";
        console.log(this.objectNotify);
    }
}
```

Please guide me how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You should have been missed something

I did exactly as your code and no issue

please see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-bqrrab